# getting error in gcc but runs successfully anyway

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc

```
#include<stdio.h>
void display(int *q,int,int);
int main(){
int a[3][4]={
             2,3,4,5,
             5,7,6,8,
             9,0,1,6
            };
display(a,3,4);
return 0;
}
void display(int *q,int row,int col){
  int i,j;
      for(i=0;i<row;i++){
           for(j=0;j<col;j++){
                 printf("%d",*(q+i*col+j));
                 }
 printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
}
```

why this code show warning in gcc that "passing argument 1 of 'display' from incompatible pointer type display(a,3,4)"?...runs successfully anyway but curious to know about error..if anyone could tell this i would be grateful..

Comment: `display(a,3,4)` should be `display(&a[0][0],3,4)` or `display((int *)a,3,4)`.

Comment: actually no need to do that i think as i am passing this to *q...so it should be done...i think....it runs anyway but showing the warning thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of "array decay" means that whenever you use an array name `a` as part of an expression, it "decays" to a pointer to the first element.

For a 1D array, this is pretty straight forward. An array `int a [10]` would decay into type `int*`.

However, in case of two-dimensional arrays, the first element of the 2D array is a 1D array. In your case, the first element of `int a[3][4]` has array type `int [4]`.

The array decay rule gives you a pointer to such an array, an *array pointer*, of type `int (*)[4]`. This type is not compatible with the type `int*` that your function expects.

However, by sheer luck, it would appear the the array pointer and a plain int pointer have the same representation on your system, and they happen to hold the same address, so the code works. You shouldn't rely on this though, it is not well-defined behavior and there is no guarantee it will work.

---

You should fix your program in the following way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display (int row, int col, int arr[row][col]);

int main()
{
  int a[3][4]=
  {
    {2,3,4,5},
    {5,7,6,8},
    {9,0,1,6},
  };

  display(3, 4, a);
  return 0;
}

void display (int row, int col, int arr[row][col])
{
  for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<col; j++)
    {
      printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Here the array type that is the function parameter will silently "get adjusted" by the compiler to a pointer to the first element, `int(*)[4]`, which matches what's passed to the function from the caller.

Comment: i did on that way actually and it went well no warning ..no error.....i used another method also 'pointer to an array thing'......i was just curious to know about that particular warning....and tbh i didn't get one thing how In my case, the first element of int a[3][4] has array type int [4]..??..:(

Answer (score 1):

Because they are incompatible pointer types, it just happens that `int *` could point to an array of `int`s and `int[][]` is an array of `int` arranged in contigous memory.

The important difference is, that while you can access `a` with a two index notation, like `a[i][j]` you can't do that with `q`.

Comment: But as he passes the array dimensions, this should work as long he doesn't try to access it as an 2D-Array, i think. And it should be okay to access it like this q[i*row+j]. (i<col,j<row) Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @KamiKaze Yes, because arrays are stored cointigously in memory.